# Sveltekit development with workers KV -- hot reloading

Tags: cloudflare, svelte, cloudflare-workers, sveltekit

Is it possible to use CloudFlare's Workers KV when developing a Svelte/kit application?

It is possible to build the app then run `wrangler dev` when using the CloudFlare Workers adapter:

```sh
npm build
wrangler dev
```

However, I haven't gotten hot module reloading working:

```
npm dev & wrangler dev
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to emulate Workers KV locally. However, I setup a local Redis instance as a substitute.

Then, I created some wrapper functions for the KV store. In development, it talks to Redis, and in production it talks to Workers KV. For instance, here's the wrapper function for `get`.

```
import { dev } from '$app/env'
import redis from 'redis'

const client = redis.createClient()
const get = promisify(client.get).bind(client)

export const getKvValue = async (key: string): Promise<string | null> => {
    return dev ? await get(key) : await KV.get(key)
}
```

---

**Update**: You can actually make things much simpler by just using an object in JavaScript—no need to download and run a Redis binary. Just make sure to JSON.stringify the values before setting them.

```
import { dev } from '$app/env'

const devKvStore = {}

const devGetKvValue = (key: string) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve(devKvStore[key] ?? null)
    })
}

const devSetKvValue = (key: string, value: unknown) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        devKvStore[key] = JSON.stringify(value)
        resolve()
    })
}

export const getKvValue = async (key: string): Promise<string | null> => {
    return dev ? await devGetKvValue(key) : await KV.get(key)
}

export const setKvValue = async (key: string, value: unknown): Promise<void> => {
    return dev ? await devSetKvValue(key, value) : await KV.put(key, value)
}
```

Comment: Really smart workaround. Rich Harris confirmed on Twitter that there is currently no “real” solution for this, so I think this hack is as good as it gets in the interim. The tweet: https://twitter.com/Rich_Harris/status/1505539552508878849

Comment: Has someone find out a way to use [miniflare](https://github.com/cloudflare/miniflare) instead?

Comment: @trenta3 Yes, see my answer for how to use miniflare with `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0):

You can use miniflare (via wrangler npm package) to emulate cloudflare bindings, and then use the local dev vite server for very fast hot reloading etc.  This works really well, at least for KV and D1.

For more detail and a working example see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77194403/1129543

The corresponding example project is https://github.com/sdarnell/cf-svelte/